# What to do about mindless acceptance of inappropriate edits?

Tags: support, editing

So I come to see my answer was edited in the way it absolutely changed original meaning.
There were three reviews of that edit with two accepted and one rejected it. So the edit now accepted. But it is wrong.

https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/55385/revisions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have the option to rollback any edits done to your posts in the revision history (the link you've included above). In your case, just click on the "rollback" label on version 2.

If you're not comfortable or sure how to engage the people you wish to discuss things with, flag the post and ask for moderator assistance in knowing what to do and/or help in facilitating a conversation with another user.

Comment: Thanks, patrix. This was helpful. Is there any way I can mention those members who accepted edit to the post to make them aware they did that without complience to the rules we all accepted?

Comment: @iskra I've pinged people in chat before if they've *repeatedly* approved blatant vandalism or radical edits, but from what I've seen of the two reviewers who approved, they are generally good at declining bad suggested edits and one review could simply have been a miss-click/tap. Calling out users for a single review might not be ideal, but FWIW if I reject a particularly bad edit I sometimes check if it got approved so I can rollback/query. [AD doesn't really have a problem with robo-reviewers and there's no review audits](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38/conversation/ad-review-audits)

Comment: The robo-approved edit is the only one that stands out IMO. The human-approved ones seem fine.

Comment: @GeorgeGarside I am not calling them names just want to get their attention. Same way I would like anybody try to get my attention if they see I did something wrong or questionable.

Comment: @iskra If you want to discuss the issue directly with the people involved, you can ping them in chat. Personally I would recommend against doing that though.